How can I plot printed data
I'm doing homework to generate a curved graph for my python course, and since it's my first time learning python, I have difficulties making an even simple code. I use Jupyter Handbook for my learning. Below is the code I'm stuck.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.optimize import fsolve

%matplotlib inline

#THE INFORMATION THE PROFESSOR GAVE ME
F=150 
M=70 
Co=350 
Ce=0 
Mabs=0 #not quite necessary information for the code
init_guess= Co/10
qm=246 
KL=0.0026 
q_prior = 0 
qe = 0 
Ce_output = [0.000001] #not quite necessary information for the code
time_output = [0.000001] #not quite necessary information for the code
qe_output = [0.000001] #not quite necessary information for the code
max_time = 24*60 #not quite necessary information for the code

func = lambda Ce : (Co-Ce)*F/(1000*M) + q_prior - qm*KL*Ce/(1+KL*Ce)

Ce_solution = fsolve(func, init_guess)
qe = qm*KL*Ce_solution/(1+KL*Ce_solution)

#THE WAY I TRY TO MAKE A PLOT
count = 1
while (count < 21):
    t = 60*70/150*count #so it's actually 28*count
    print('Ce',Ce_solution,'qe',qe,'t',t)
    plt.plot(t, Ce)
    count = count + 1
    qm = qe
    Ce_solution = fsolve(func, init_guess)
    qe = qm*KL*Ce_solution/(1+KL*Ce_solution)

plt.xlim([0,560])
plt.ylim([0,350])
plt.show()

Using this code, I get 20 (Ce, ge, t) data printed and a blank diagram. What I want is the 20 data and a Ce-t curved graph(t on x axis; Ce on y axis) according to the 20 data. I think I should relocate the plt.plot(t, Ce) inside the while loop, but I can't make a guess how. Can you teach me what I'm missing? Thank you.

When you use the plot function within the while loop, you end up making a lot of unnecessary plots. What you need to do is to store your time variables t and your Ce_solution in lists (or equivalent) and then plot after the while loop. You can do something like this:
count = 1
times = []
list_of_ce = []
while (count < 21):
    t = 60*70/150*count #so it's actually 28*count
    print('Ce',Ce_solution,'qe',qe,'t',t)
    count = count + 1
    qm = qe
    Ce_solution = fsolve(func, init_guess)
    qe = qm*KL*Ce_solution/(1+KL*Ce_solution)

    times.append(t)
    list_of_ce.append(Ce_solution)

plt.plot(times, list_of_ce, 'k.-')

plt.xlim([0,560])
plt.ylim([0,350])
plt.show('')

What the code does is that it saves your variables in lists as the while loop runs, and then does the plotting after the while loop has completed.
